# How to disable "Send a birthday message!" in Facebook Messenger?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

In Facebook comes always the notification "Send a birthday message!" in the messenger everytime when Facebook friends have their birthday.

There is no push message, but the icon gets the red notification sign, which is kinda anoying, because I have to check it then for new messages which I may have received.

It looks like this in a web browser:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The birthday notifications are turned of in general in my Facebook profile, but these messages are still showing up since a few weeks.

How can I switch off these notifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the source of those messenger birthday notifications is [**M**, Facebook's virtual assistant / bot](https://www.cnbc.com/2017/06/26/facebook-messenger-m-assistant-suggests-happy-birthday.html).

[**M** was killed in January 2018](https://www.cnet.com/news/facebook-is-killing-m-its-personal-chatbot-assistant/), so it probably won't suggest any more birthday greetings such as those.

Comment: It stopped bugging me on its own a few weeks ago, so I think you could be right with the virtual assistent.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to Settings > Notifications > On Facebook > Birthdays > Off

Here is a [shortcut link](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=notifications&section=on_facebook&view).

Comment: As I already wrote, the birthday notifications are turned off.